# Assign value to the variable based on returning data from the subscribe in Angular . (Is it possible ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs-observables

```
somefunction(){
    isUserLoggedin(): boolean {
        this.isUserInDB().subscribe((result: any) => {
          if (result.code === 200) {
            return true;
          }
        });
      return false;
  }
```

*isUserInDB(): this API takes a token from localstorage and returns 200 if the user exists in DB or returns 404 if the user does not exist in DB (someone is trying to try his/her own token.)*

**In this I always get false I know because of first return false is executed and then subscribe method is invoked. So I want to know that is that any other way exists or I just doing some extra stuff ?**

Comment: The subscription is asynchronous. The application has no idea of when the observable will emit it's value. So there is no way to return the value from the subscription synchronously. In other words, you need to subscribe where it's response is required.

Comment: isUserLoggedin is missing .pipe(first()) so the subscribtion destroy himself every call, otherwise if you call isUserLoggedin a second time, the subscribe is going to trigger 2 times and so on and so on. You are accumulating subscribtions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a property of the class and initialize it as false:

```
isUserInDb = false
```

When the component is created, change the property to true if the result's status is success:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isUserInDB().subscribe((result: any) => {
        if (result.code === 200) {
            this.isUserInDb = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `this.isUserInDB()` is asynchronous `isUserLoggedin` will always return false. What you can do is return the observable instead of boolean and handle this where you are calling this functon:

```
isUserLoggedin(): Observable<any> { // replace any with your type
    return this.isUserInDB();
}
```

and where ever you want to perform some logic based on user login, you can subscribe to this function and perform your task:

```
isUserLoggedIn.subscribe((result: any) => {
          if (result.code === 200) {
             // Your code
          }
```

Ideally, in your login flow you should store the login status of the user in some service and return the same.

Answer (score 0):

my take on this would be to sync it thanks to async/await

```
async isUserLoggedin(): Promise<boolean> {
   const result = await this.isUserInDB().pipe(first()).toPromise();

   if (result.code === 200) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
async somefunction(): Promise<void> {
    const logged = await this.isUserLoggedin();
}
```